# How to increase the font size of a Text widget?

Tags: python, textbox, tkinter, block, font-size

How to increase the font size of a Text widget?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are several ways to specify a font: the simplest is a tuple of the form `(family, size, style)`.

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
text=tk.Text(width = 40, height=4, font=("Helvetica", 32))
text.pack()    
root.mainloop()
```

An arguably better solution is to create a font object, since the font will exist as an object and can be modified at runtime.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font

root=tk.Tk()
text_font = Font(family="Helvetica", size=32)
text=tk.Text(width = 40, height=4, font=text_font)
text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

By using the `Font` class, you can change the font at any time, and every widget that uses the font will automatically be updated.

For example, to change the size of the font for several widgets, you can change it once in the font and all widgets that use the font will see the change:

```
text_font = Font(family="Helvetica", size=32)
text1 = tk.Text(..., font=text_font)
text2 = tk.Text(..., font=text_font)
label = tk.Label(..., font=text_font)
...
text_font.configure(weight="bold", size=24)
```